# PHP-Why do i get Undefined variable after using require_once?

Tags: php, arrays, variables, curl, global-variables

hello I tell them I have the following problem: 
I have 2 files which is a class in php and the other a script that calls this class and displays the results, the funny thing is that on my computer and localhost works fine on other servers that have php 5.4 also like running, but in hostmonster worked only one day and the next day stopped working, I provide the support and say it's my thing the quue Error code throws me is:

> PHP Notice:  Undefined variable: result in /home/user/public_html/rox.php on line 25

code the rox.php

```
    <?php
          // use the IceCast class to obtain the stream details
          require_once('icecast.php');
          $oIceCast = new IceCast();

          // set server and mount
          $server = 'http://giss.tv:8000';
          $file   = '/status.xsl?mount=/radiosuguaFM.mp3';

          $oIceCast->setUrl($server,$file);
          $status = $oIceCast->getStatus();
          $result .= <<<EOF
    <div><strong>Nombre</strong> {$status['title']}</div>
    <div><strong>Descripcion</strong> {$status['description']}</div>
    <div><strong>Inicio de la transmision</strong> {$status['mount_start']}</div>
    <div><strong>Escuchas</strong> {$status['listeners']}</div>
    <div><strong>Max escuchas</strong> {$status['most_listeners']}</div>
    <div><strong>Url</strong> {$status['url']}</div>
    <div><strong>Artista actual</strong> {$status['now_playing']['artist']}</div>
    <div><strong>Track actual</strong> {$status['now_playing']['track']}</div>
    <audio controls>
    <source src="http://giss.tv:8000/radiosuguaFM.mp3">
    <!-- This is Where You Enter Your Flash Fall Back -->
    </audio>
EOF;
    ?>
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
      <meta charset="utf-8" />
      <meta property="og:site_name" content="Script Tutorials" />
      <meta property="og:title" content="Script to read information from audio stream | Script Tutorials" />
      <meta property="og:image" content="http://www.script-tutorials.com/demos/398/thumb.png" />
      <meta property="og:type" content="website" />
      <meta name="description" content="Script to read information from audio stream - Script Tutorials">
      <title>Script to read information from audio stream | Script Tutorials</title>
      <link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">
    </head>
    <body>
      <div class="container">
        <?= $result ?>
      </div><!--/.container-->
    </body>
    </html>
?>
```

this code de class icecast.php:

```
<?php
class IceCast {
  var $server = '';
  var $stats_file = "/status.xsl";
  var $radio_info = array();

  function __construct() {
    //build array to store our radio stats for later use        
    $this->radio_info['server'] = $this->server;
    $this->radio_info['title'] = 'Offline';
    $this->radio_info['description'] = 'Radio offline';
    $this->radio_info['content_type'] = '';
    $this->radio_info['mount_start'] = '';
    $this->radio_info['bit_rate'] = '';
    $this->radio_info['listeners'] = '';
    $this->radio_info['most_listeners'] = '';
    $this->radio_info['genre'] = '';
    $this->radio_info['url'] = '';
    $this->radio_info['now_playing'] = array();
    $this->radio_info['now_playing']['artist'] = 'Unknown';
    $this->radio_info['now_playing']['track'] = 'Unknown';
  }

    function setUrl($url,$file) {
        $this->server=$url;
        $this->stats_file=$file;
        $this->radio_info['server'] = $this->server;
    }

  private function fetch() {
    //create a new curl resource
    $ch = curl_init();

    //set url
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL, $this->server . $this->stats_file);

    //return as a string
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);

    //$output = our stauts.xsl file
    $output = curl_exec($ch);

    //close curl resource to free up system resources
    curl_close($ch);

    return $output;
  }

  function getStatus() {
    $output = $this->fetch();

    //loop through $ouput and sort into our different arrays
    $temp_array = array();

    $search_for = "<td\s[^>]*class=\"streamdata\">(.*)<\/td>";
    $search_td = array('<td class="streamdata">', '</td>');


    if (preg_match_all("/$search_for/siU", $output, $matches)) {
      foreach ($matches[0] as $match) {
        $to_push = str_replace($search_td, '', $match);
        $to_push = trim($to_push);
        array_push($temp_array, $to_push);
      }
    }

    if (count($temp_array)) {
      //sort our temp array into our ral array
      $this->radio_info['title'] = $temp_array[0];
      $this->radio_info['description'] = $temp_array[1];
      $this->radio_info['content_type'] = $temp_array[2];
      $this->radio_info['mount_start'] = $temp_array[3];
      $this->radio_info['bit_rate'] = $temp_array[4];
      $this->radio_info['listeners'] = $temp_array[5];
      $this->radio_info['most_listeners'] = $temp_array[6];
      $this->radio_info['genre'] = $temp_array[7];
      $this->radio_info['url'] = $temp_array[8];

      if (isset($temp_array[9])) {
        $x = explode(" - ", $temp_array[9]);
        $this->radio_info['now_playing']['artist'] = $x[0];
        $this->radio_info['now_playing']['track'] = $x[1];
      }
    }
    return $this->radio_info;
  }
}
?>
```

thank you very much for your help

Comment: Which line is line 25?

Comment: Sidenote: `EOF;` contains 4 spaces from the left to the beginning of `E`, least in your question. Remove them if they are in your actual working code.

Answer (score 1):

first check whether it is defined or not then use

i think because of this `$result .= <<<EOF` you are getting the error

```
require_once('icecast.php');
$oIceCast = new IceCast();
.....
......

if(empty($result))
{
$result = '';
}
.....
.....

$result .= <<<EOF.....
.......
.......
```

Comment: I added the following to the script:
if(empty($result))
{
$result = 'Not Variable';
}
and print Not Variable

Answer (score 1):

You're trying to *append* to an existing variable:

```
$result .= <<<EOF
```

But `$result` does in fact not exist here.
You simple want to create and assign the variable:

```
$result = <<<EOF
```

Comment: I did what you told me to remove the '.' 
and I added the following to the script: `if(empty($result)) { $result = 'Not Variable'; }` and print 
Nombre Offline
Descripcion Radio offline
Inicio de la transmision
Escuchas
Max escuchas
Url
Artista actual Unknown
Track actual Unknown
and my localhost print 
Nombre Radio Sugua
Descripcion Radio comunitaria garifuna de sambo creek
Inicio de la transmision Fri, 20 Jun 2014 21:41:38 +0200
Escuchas 1
Max escuchas 5
Url
Artista actual
Track actual